# trying to save an html5 canvas but its blank

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am using a website called cesium which shows me a globe of the world, it uses html5. Basically I want to save everything I see on the screen, I am new to html5/javascript...

Everytime I tried to save the canvas it kept showing me a blank black screen. I thought this maybe because the canvas has not finished loading so I put it inside an onload function. Also tried using a timer to sleep the script from saving until after it loads.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var scene = viewer.scene;
    var canvas = scene.canvas;
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
    window.location.href=image;
}
```

I also read it could be something related to CORS (cross origin resource sharing) but I am not getting any errors. Sorry I know this has been asked, but I am new to html5 and the other solutions did not help me.

edit:

Thanks for your help, as I am new to this I took a lot of time trying to understand it, even got a response on the cesium forum. I was hoping you could help me understand the issue some more..

```
require(['Cesium'], function(Cesium) {
    "use strict";

    // Cesium.CesiumWidget is similar to Cesium.Viewer, but
    // is trimmed down.  It is just a widget for the 3D globe;
    // it does not include the animation, imagery selection,
    // and other widgets, nor does it depend on the third-party
    // Knockout library.
    var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer',
        {
        contextOptions:{webgl:{preserveDrawingBuffer : true}
                           }});
    var scene = widget.scene;   

    var canvas = scene.canvas;
    var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(dataUrl,'Screenshot','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, resizable=yes');
    Sandcastle.finishedLoading();
});
```

this is my code, I set the preserveDrawingBuffer to true but I still get a blank image, the cesium forum told me this

```
We capture the WebGL canvas on a couple of projects including Doarama.  You need to initialize the WebGL context with preserveDrawingBuffer enabled before capturing.  This can be done in Cesium like this...

  var scene = new Cesium.Scene(canvas, {
    webgl : {
      preserveDrawingBuffer : true
    }
  }, creditContainer);
```

Comment: Isnt cesium implemented in WebGL? If yes, you need first to draw the WebGL screen in the canvas.

Comment: yeah it is, sorry I am not familiar with WebGL either. I will go and try to find out how to do that and comment on if it worked

Answer (score 4):

I recognize this question is now old, but I had the same problem and came across the solution.  When you initialize your `Viewer` you can pass in the option to `preserveDrawingBuffer` directly, like this:

```
viewer=new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer',{
    contextOptions: {
        webgl:{preserveDrawingBuffer:true}
    }
});
```

This will give you the behavior you need.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that the 'webgl' key had to be set and just passed in preserveDrawingBuffer directly, this fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:

You are right, the method `toDataURL` is a method of canvas, so its independent of the context we are using. The snipped I posted here (I will leave it in the end of the post) I used it to compose the various layer that I have.

I just tested here, and `toDataURL` only worked fine after setting `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`.

```
gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl",{preserveDrawingBuffer:true});
```

Here's the trick part. Assuming that you cant modified the code and you celsium get the context only once. You can override the variable assigned to the context with a new context but now with this parameter. I havent tried this on celsium yet, but worked it worked in [this example](http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson04/index.html).

Unfortunately, I dont have time right now to find where exactly cesium get the context and if it only get once. Although, I was able to track the context 'creation' down to:

```
this._originalGLContext=i.getContext("webgl",s)||i.getContext("experimental-webgl",s);
this._gl=this._originalGLContext;
```

Anyway, I hope you have access to the code and can just add the `preserveDrawingBuffer` parameter.

```
var dataUrl = document.getElementById("webglCanvas").toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(dataUrl,'Screenshot','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, resizable=yes');
```

Comment: I don't know what the webgl id is because I don't see it, all I know is that using cesium sandcastle it shows me that everything is inside an id called cesiumContainer. I tried your code minus the ctx.drawimage and it showed a blank white image, tried guessing some id's but nada.

Comment: so after trying to use the preserverdrawingbuffer and failing, I put the code into the rendering method of webgl, and it saved some images. However it saved one per frame, so I am not sure how to find out when the rendering completes :/

Comment: @CatznDogz What do you mean 1 per frame? I mean, cant you get what you want if you call the method to after you render everything you want and before the clear method?

Comment: I mean I think its saving a canvas each time  it renders something on the screen because I placed the code inside a drawing method. I want to put it where the rendering ends, but the code is massive and I am not having luck. I read I need to save the canvas after render completes, but before webgl clears itself and gives control back to JS.

Comment: @CatznDogz I think I understand your problem. Well, I would try to create a global boolean variable and use it inside the draw. It will be initially `false` (not saving the frame). Whenever I wanted a frame saved I would change this bool to `true`. I know its a hack but may work for you.

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately I hit hurdle after hurdle. I got the save to show me the canvas image (the globe and stars), however when I drew a polyline or polygon, the image would return blank again! the only reason I want to save the canvas is to show my drawings and traces with polygons. Webgl looks to massive to fix this over night..cesium uses Geometry and Primitives to draw polygons...Im still learning how webgl does it natively. I can't find out if the polygons are drawn ONTO the canvas or over it or on another canvas...:X